# Calculating Airline Rank in Python - NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I could use some help for my programming class. I think I've almost got this down, but I keep getting the "NameError: name 'flight_miles' is not defined" when I try to run my main module. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is my program.

```
def get_flights_purchased():
    flights_purchased = 0
    while flights_purchased is not int:
        try:
            flights_purchased = int(input("Please enter the number of flights that you purchased this month "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a number. Please provide a whole number')
    return flights_purchased

def calculate_flight_miles_earned(flights_purchased):
    flight_miles = 0
    if flights_purchased == 0:
        flight_miles = 100

    elif flights_purchased == 1:
        flight_miles = 5

    elif flights_purchased == 2:
        flight_miles = 15

    elif flights_purchased == 3:
        flight_miles = 30

    elif flights_purchased > 3:
        flight_miles = 60

def output_flight_tier(flight_miles):

    if flight_miles == 0:
        print("You haven't flown with us yet, so you don't have a flight tier.")
    elif flight_miles == 5:
        print("You are in the economy airline tier")
    elif flight_miles == 15:
        print(" You are in the MVP airline tier")
    elif flight_miles == 30:
        print("You are in the MVP GOLD airline tier")
    elif flight_miles > 30:
        print("You are in the MVP GOLD tier!")

def final_evaluation(flights, output_flight_tier):
    evaluation = ""
    if flights < 15:
        evaluation = "You are not a frequent flyer"
    elif flights > 15:
        evaluation = "You are a frequent flyer"
    return evaluation

def output_point(get_flights_purchased, calculate_flight_miles_earned, output_flight_tier, final_evaluation):

    print("The number of flights you have purchased is ", flights_purchased)
    print(" The total # of miles earned from flights you have purchased is ", flights)
    print("The final evaluation is", final_evaluation)

def main():
     flights_purchased = 0
     flight_miles = 0
     evaluation = ""
     flights_purchased = get_flights_purchased()
     flight_miles = calculate_flight_miles_earned(flights_purchased)
     output_flight_tier(flight_miles)
     evaluation = final_evaluation(flights, output_flight_tier)
     output_point(get_flights_purchased, calculate_flight_miles_earned,                output_flight_tier, final_evaluation)

main()
```

Comment: ```flights = flight_miles(calculate_flight_miles_earned)``` `flight_miles` isn't a function defined anywhere in your code?

Comment: you are calling the function flight_miles in main but not defined anywhere?

Comment: Because that `flight_miles` is not defined there :) (does not exists). Try to find that: press CTRL+F and write there flight_miles. You have no global object, no global variable, no global function... nothing about global flight_miles. So, the Python interpreter don't know the flight_miles name. It's a global variable ? It's a function ? Or what is it ? You have to say in main, which is exactly the name because the main function does not know this name (since there is no global function with this name). If you mean a global variable, then you must add: `global flight_miles` into main function.

Comment: Or easier to explain from me: You try to call `flight_miles()`, which does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main errors are still as a result of erroneous function calls.

For example, output_point takes some parameters, but doesn't use those parameters in its execution.

I have made a few edits to your code so that it works, as I think that is simpler than trying to explain each one. I have commented on the line before each edit so that you understand where the code went wrong.

```
def get_flights_purchased():
    flights_purchased = -1
    # "int" is a type, so flights_purchased is not going to equal "int"
    while flights_purchased == -1:
        try:
            flights_purchased = int(input("Please enter the number of flights that you purchased this month "))
        except ValueError:
            print('That is not a number. Please provide a whole number')
    return flights_purchased

def calculate_flight_miles_earned(flights_purchased):
    flight_miles = 0
    if flights_purchased == 0:
        flight_miles = 100

    elif flights_purchased == 1:
        flight_miles = 5

    elif flights_purchased == 2:
        flight_miles = 15

    elif flights_purchased == 3:
        flight_miles = 30

    elif flights_purchased > 3:
        flight_miles = 60

    #critical line - if you do not return this value, flight_miles will not be in main
    return flight_miles

def output_flight_tier(flight_miles):

    if flight_miles == 0:
        print("You haven't flown with us yet, so you don't have a flight tier.")
    elif flight_miles == 5:
        print("You are in the economy airline tier")
    elif flight_miles == 15:
        print(" You are in the MVP airline tier")
    elif flight_miles == 30:
        print("You are in the MVP GOLD airline tier")
    elif flight_miles > 30:
        print("You are in the MVP GOLD tier!")

def final_evaluation(flights, output_flight_tier):
    evaluation = ""
    #need an equal sign in one of these two conditions, as if flights = 15, evaluation will remain ""
    #for example, if flights <= 15 instead of flights < 15
    if flights < 15:
        evaluation = "You are not a frequent flyer"
    elif flights > 15:
        evaluation = "You are a frequent flyer"
    return evaluation

# the parameters of the subprogram must match the values used in the subprogram
# the parameters should be values, not other subprograms
def output_point(flights_purchased, flights, final_evaluation):
    print("The number of flights you have purchased is ", flights_purchased)
    print(" The total # of miles earned from flights you have purchased is ", flights)
    print("The final evaluation is", final_evaluation)

def main():
     flights_purchased = 0
     flight_miles = 0
     evaluation = ""
     flights_purchased = get_flights_purchased()
     flight_miles = calculate_flight_miles_earned(flights_purchased)
     output_flight_tier(flight_miles)
     #changed flights to flight_miles
     evaluation = final_evaluation(flight_miles, output_flight_tier)
     #changed parameters to match the parameters of output_point
     output_point(flights_purchased, flight_miles, evaluation)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You call your second subprogram incorrectly.
Instead of:

```
flight_miles(calculate_flight_miles_earned)
```

it should be:

```
calculate_flight_miles_earned(flights_purchased)
```

In general, when you call a function, it should be in the form:

```
return_value = function(parameter1, parameter2...)
```

Your code has a number of other instances where this error has been made, but using the format above should resolve them. If you have no return value, just call

```
function(parameters)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added your recommended change to the code by I still receive the following error:  `NameError: name 'flight_miles' is not defined`

Comment: This is because the variable "flight_miles" is not defined in global scope (i.e. outside of a subprogram). To rectify, change the name of the variable "flights" to "flight_miles" so that the variable is defined. You'll also need to change "output_flight_tier = flight_miles" to read "output_flight_tier(flight_miles)".

Comment: Thanks for your response again. I added `flight_miles = 0` as a global variable but still can't get it to work. I updated my code if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

adding to random.george 11's answer, you never actually defined '`flight_miles`' in `main`, only in `calculate_flight_miles_earned`. The value isn't carried over when you call it again in `main` in `output_flight_tier = flight_miles`

Answer (score 0):

The return is out of the function scope.

```
def get_flights_purchased():
    flights_purchased = 0
    while flights_purchased is not int:
         try:
            flights_purchased = int(input("Please enter the number of 
                                       flights that you purchased this 
                                       month "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('That is not a number. Please provide a whole number')
return flights_purchased
```

Comment: I mistakenly forgot to indent it on my post. It was already indented within my code :)

Comment: It's kinda normal forget about indentation when it's beginner, that's why i mention it. =) keep it up man.